# Haven't recieved a text for collection of CDS

Tags: visa, france

I had applied for my [CDS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titre_de_s%C3%A9jour) last month August, and havent yet recieved the text message from them for the collection of the card. Would they send an email or just a text for the collection?

Answer (score 1):

Different prefectures are operating in different ways.

You don't mention your Departement but it has been the practice in Dept 16 (for example) to send the WARP by registered post rather than require a visit to the prefecture to collect - probably because of Covid restrictions and to limit exposure of their staff.